# Trigger a script via clipboard input

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, arguments, clipboard

This might be a bit ambitious, but. . .Is there a way to trigger a script to run when the clipboard receives data? I am hoping to not only have a bash script run, but to also extract and use the clipboard input as an argument. As an example, highlight text and when copied (via CTRL+C for instance), once that text hits the clipboard, the script will take it in as an argument and execute accordingly. I do realize the script will have to be running, I don't want something that simply records everything that passes through, only on use case. Perhaps python or golang could accomplish this with bash?

Comment: Is it for particular application or for whole desktop?

Comment: It's really for a lot of idea I have for scripts. It just makes it much quicker if this method can work. For instance, if I am using a tool like youtube-dl and build a script around that. It would be nice to start the script in a 'listen mode' and simply launch the functions I need once I have copied whatever url to the clipboard.